# Chrome Extension changeInfo.status

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just tried to add a tab listener to a chrome extension I've been fooling around with but I have run into sort of an infinite loop problem.

Here is the code that I tried

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) 
{
    if(changeInfo.status === "loading")
    {
        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {'url': 'main.html'});
    }

});
```

What happens is as soon as the tab starts loading it sends the url too the main.html. Only problem is it triggers the onUpdated and continues to send the page to main.html

Is there a way around this. The only thing I can think is test if the url contains main.html but that feels a little hacky.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, right when the page starts to load I want to display a html file from from within the extension. Problem when I redirect to the new page it triggers the onUpdated listener and continues to send to the main.html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no better way, you can't remove or temporary disable a listener.

Only instead of checking if url contains "main.html", it would be better to check if url is equal to:

```
chrome-extension://<your_extension_id>/main.html
```

Comment: That makes sense, I thought checking for main.html alone might cause problems. Thanks heaps for the reply